# Has Darkwing Duck ever met Scrooge McDuck?

Tags: disney, ducktales, darkwing-duck

Has Darkwing Duck ever met Scrooge, in any media, new or old?

Comment: https://www.slashfilm.com/darkwing-duck-connected-to-ducktales/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Darkwing Duck and Scrooge McDuck have met on several occasions.

In [***The Legend of the Chaos God***](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Legend_of_the_Chaos_God) (1994) Scrooge hires Darkwing Duck to recover an artifact. At the end he and Darkwing are seen in the same room together.

[image]
<sub><sup>**[Disney Adventures - July 30, 1994: *"The Legend of the Chaos God"*](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Disney_Adventures)**</sup></sub>

---

In [*Dangerous Currency*](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Dangerous_Currency) (2011) (starting in [Duck Tales #5 and #6](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/DuckTales_(comic_books)#The_Boom.21_Studios_title_.282011.29) and ending in [Darkwing Duck #17 and #18](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Darkwing_Duck_(Boom!_Studios))) he and Darkwing Duck have several conversations.

[image]
**<sub><sup>[Ducktales #6, *"Dangerous Currency, Part II"*](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Dangerous_Currency).</sup></sub>**

---

Comment: And this answer the question: Has Darkwing Duck ever met GizmoDuck?

Comment: Gizmoduck was a member of DD's team ("Justice Ducks") in the animated series. The team included: Darkwing, Gizmoduck, Morgana Macawber, Neptunia, and Stegmutt. They came together to fight the Fearsome Five: Negaduck, Megavolt, Quackerjack, Bushroot, and Liquidator.

Comment: Dangerous Currency is non-canon according to Disney.

Comment: @TheAsh - I believe the quote is "*retconned as non-canon*". The older serial is, as far as I'm aware, still part of the main canon but then these comics go back nearly a century now, so there's no part of the older comics that hasn't been repeatedly contradicted by later events.

Comment: @Valorum As far as I'm aware, Disney was upset at Boom's studios story.

Comment: There were "justice ducks"? We've got Paperinik and Super Goofy but I wonder if there are more Disney characters that are "obviously" based on DC and Marvel stock?

Answer (score 1):

### *DuckTales* 2017 (Spoilers)

Scrooge McDuck and Darkwing Duck interact several times through the course of the show.

At the beginning of *DuckTales*, *Darkwing Duck* is a fictional, live-action (to them) show within the show. In season 2's "The Duck Knight Returns!" Scrooge funds a high budget reboot of the show and meets Drake Mallard, the new actor (shown with his arms up in the first picture).

[image]

[image]

Drake Mallard eventually decides to be Darkwing Duck for real, turning him into an actual superhero. This new version meets Scrooge in season 3's "Let's Get Dangerous! Part 2: A Case of Mistaken Identity."

[image]

Darkwing clearly made a good impression, as he is joins the protagonists in all three episodes of the show's finale. He interacts with Scrooge in each.

[image]

[image]

[image]